# cURL randomly stopped working

Tags: curl, mobileme

In the middle of writing an application that heavily relies on cURL I came across an error. The error cURL returns is

```
<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Error</TITLE></HEAD><BODY>
An error occurred while processing your request.<p>
Reference&#32;&#35;179&#46;671d1f45&#46;1280621802&#46;1a9c0add
</BODY></HTML>
```

The command I use is

```
curl -T /test.txt http://idisk.me.com/myAccount/Public/myFolder/
```

MyAccount and MyFolder I replace with the correct info. Could it be that my host (Apple) is now denying curl uploads for some reason?

Thanks for any help this is really puzzling

Answer (score 2):

Try using a different user-agent:

```
curl -A 'other user agent' -T /test.txt http://idisk.me.com/myAccount/Public/myFolder/
```

Comment: Sorry to ask but I haven't heard of other user agent. Could you explain a little more? Also I still get the error...

Comment: See [user agent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent).  It's a string that identifies the HTTP client.  Some servers block curl, which you can bypass by spoofing a different agent (e.g. IE's, `Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.0)`),

Comment: Okay thanks I'll try that again. So I would replace 'other user agent' with something like Mozilla/4.0 ?

Comment: Or the whole string I gave.  You can also find lists of [common user agents](http://whatsmyuseragent.com/CommonUserAgents.asp) to try.

Comment: Hmmm now I just get unauthorized. If I run it again I get the error I previously got.

Answer (score 0):

The error you are receiving is an error typically returned by Akamai CDN. If you have access to Akamai Control Portal, then you should go to the support section and look for the error translator tool. There you can insert the Reference number you get in return with cURL. In this particular case it is Ref:#179.671d1f45.1280621802.1a9c0add

The error could be related to wrong credentials, maximum number of requests per day reached, etc.

Once you translate the error, it will tell you exactly why the error response at which point you can troubleshoot much easily.